# css 4 columns, 6 items not aligning correct

Tags: css

Please check the image i dont know what code to post to make you understand. Check the code i have found in style.css ...
Its from  wordpress template. Not aligning if 6 items on grid or 7 items. I there any way to fix this behaviour using css?

this is the wrong behaviour

[image]

this is the right behaviour

[image]

```
/* Post Style: Grid Posts
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
.boxwp-grid-posts{overflow:hidden;display:-webkit-box;display:-webkit-flex;display:-moz-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-webkit-flex-direction:row;-moz-box-orient:horizontal;-moz-box-direction:normal;-ms-flex-direction:row;flex-direction:row;-webkit-box-pack:justify;-webkit-justify-content:space-between;-moz-box-pack:justify;-ms-flex-pack:justify;justify-content:space-between;-webkit-box-align:stretch;-webkit-align-items:stretch;-moz-box-align:stretch;-ms-flex-align:stretch;align-items:stretch;-webkit-flex-wrap:wrap;-ms-flex-wrap:wrap;flex-wrap:wrap;-webkit-align-content:stretch;-ms-flex-line-pack:stretch;align-content:stretch;padding:0 5px;}
.boxwp-grid-post{position:relative;height:auto;padding:0;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:20px;margin-right:2%;overflow:hidden;}
.boxwp-grid-post.boxwp-4-col{float:left;width:23.5%;-webkit-box-flex:0;-webkit-flex:0 0 23.5%;-moz-box-flex:0;-ms-flex:0 0 23.5%;flex:0 0 23.5%;}
.boxwp-grid-post.boxwp-4-col:nth-of-type(4n+4){margin-right:0;}
.boxwp-grid-post.boxwp-4-col:nth-of-type(4n+1){clear:both;}
.boxwp-grid-post a{text-decoration:none;}
.boxwp-grid-post-thumbnail{width:100%;margin:0 0 0 0;float:none;position:relative;overflow:hidden;}
.boxwp-grid-post-thumbnail img{width:100%;max-width:100%;height:auto;display:block;-webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;-o-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;opacity:1;-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;-moz-backface-visibility:hidden;backface-visibility:hidden;}
.boxwp-grid-post-thumbnail img:hover{opacity:0.8;}
.boxwp-grid-post-details{width:100%;height:auto;float:none;position:relative;padding:0;}
.boxwp-grid-post-details-full{width:100%;height:auto;float:none;position:relative;padding:0;}
.boxwp-grid-post-categories{margin-bottom:0;text-align:center;position:absolute;top:40px;left:2px;right:2px;opacity:0;-webkit-transition:all 1.5s linear;-o-transition:all 1.5s linear;-moz-transition:all 1.5s linear;transition:all 1.5s linear;-webkit-animation-duration:1s;-moz-animation-duration:1s;-o-animation-duration:1s;animation-duration:1s;-webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;-moz-animation-fill-mode:both;-o-animation-fill-mode:both;animation-fill-mode:both;}
.boxwp-grid-post-thumbnail:hover .boxwp-grid-post-categories{opacity:1;-webkit-animation-name:boxwp-bounceInDown;animation-name:boxwp-bounceInDown;}
.boxwp-grid-post-categories a{display:inline-block;color:#ffffff !important;background:#7f181b !important;padding:3px 5px;font:normal normal 11px Oswald,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;line-height:1;margin:0 3px 2px 0;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:0.5px;-webkit-animation-duration:1s;-moz-animation-duration:1s;-o-animation-duration:1s;animation-duration:1s;-webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;-moz-animation-fill-mode:both;-o-animation-fill-mode:both;animation-fill-mode:both;}
.boxwp-grid-post-categories a:before{content:"\f07c";font-family:FontAwesome;font-style:normal;font-weight:inherit;text-decoration:none;display:inline-block;margin-right:2px;vertical-align:top;}
.boxwp-grid-post-categories a:last-child{margin:0 0 0 0;}
.boxwp-grid-post-categories a:hover{color:#ffffff !important;background:#000000 !important;-webkit-animation-duration:0.75s;-moz-animation-duration:0.75s;-o-animation-duration:0.75s;animation-duration:0.75s;-webkit-animation-name:boxwp-fadein;-moz-animation-name:boxwp-fadein;-o-animation-name:boxwp-fadein;animation-name:boxwp-fadein;}
.boxwp-grid-post-title{font:normal bold 17px 'Playfair Display',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#000000 !important;margin:6px 0 0 0;line-height:1.2;text-transform:none;text-align:center;padding:0;letter-spacing:-0.4px;}
.boxwp-grid-post-title a{color:#000000 !important;}
.boxwp-grid-post-title a:hover{color:#333333 !important;}
.boxwp-grid-post:first-child .boxwp-grid-post-title{}
.boxwp-grid-post-snippet{display:block;text-align:center;margin:2px 0 2px 0;padding:0;color:#ffffff !important;font:normal normal 12px Domine,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;line-height:1.3;}
.boxwp-grid-post-snippet p{margin:0;}
.boxwp-grid-post-snippet a,.boxwp-grid-post-snippet a:hover{color:#ffffff !important;}
.boxwp-grid-post-footer{margin:0;font:normal normal 11px Oswald,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;text-transform:uppercase;color:#ffffff !important;line-height:1;text-align:center;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);padding:0;opacity:1;transform:scaleX(1);transition:all 0.4s linear;}
.boxwp-grid-post-footer-inside{padding:5px 3px;}
.boxwp-grid-post-inside:hover .boxwp-grid-post-footer{opacity:1;transform:scaleX(1);background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);}
.boxwp-grid-post-footer a{color:#ffffff !important;display:inline-block;}
.boxwp-grid-post-footer a:hover{color:#ffffff !important;}
.boxwp-grid-post-footer i{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;}
.boxwp-grid-post-author{display:inline-block;line-height:1;margin: 0 0 0 0;}
.boxwp-grid-post-date{display:inline-block;line-height:1;margin: 0 0 0 0;}
.boxwp-grid-post-dot-div{margin:0 5px 0 5px;display:inline-block;line-height:1;}
.boxwp-grid-post-comment{display:inline-block;line-height:1;margin: 0 0 0 0;}
.boxwp-grid-post-meta:before{content:'\2022';margin-right:5px;margin-left:5px;}
.boxwp-grid-post-meta:first-child:before{content:'';margin-right:0;margin-left:0;}
.boxwp-grid-post-read-more{margin:0;text-align:center;font:normal normal 12px Oswald,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;text-transform:uppercase;opacity:0;transition:all 0.2s linear;left:0;right:0;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
.boxwp-grid-post-thumbnail:hover .boxwp-grid-post-read-more{opacity:1;}
.boxwp-grid-post-read-more a{display:block;background:#000000 !important;color:#ffffff !important;padding:10px 8px;line-height:1;-webkit-animation-duration:1s;-moz-animation-duration:1s;-o-animation-duration:1s;animation-duration:1s;-webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;-moz-animation-fill-mode:both;-o-animation-fill-mode:both;animation-fill-mode:both;}
.boxwp-grid-post-read-more a:hover{background:#000000 !important;color:#ffffff !important;}
.boxwp-grid-post-read-more a:after{content:"\f138";font-family:FontAwesome;font-style:normal;font-weight:inherit;text-decoration:none;display:inline-block;margin-left:5px;vertical-align:top;}
.boxwp-grid-post-mask{-webkit-transition:all 0.4s ease-in-out;-o-transition:all 0.4s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:all 0.4s ease-in-out;transition:all 0.4s ease-in-out;opacity:0;position:absolute;bottom:-200px;left:0;width:100%;padding:0;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);text-align:center;-webkit-animation-duration:1s;-moz-animation-duration:1s;-o-animation-duration:1s;animation-duration:1s;-webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;-moz-animation-fill-mode:both;-o-animation-fill-mode:both;animation-fill-mode:both;}
.boxwp-grid-post-mask-inside{position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;padding:0;}
.boxwp-grid-post-thumbnail:hover .boxwp-grid-post-mask{opacity:1;bottom:0;}
.boxwp-grid-snippet-mask{-webkit-transition:all 0.4s ease-in-out;-o-transition:all 0.4s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:all 0.4s ease-in-out;transition:all 0.4s ease-in-out;opacity:1;position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;width:100%;padding:0;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);text-align:center;-webkit-animation-duration:1s;-moz-animation-duration:1s;-o-animation-duration:1s;animation-duration:1s;-webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;-moz-animation-fill-mode:both;-o-animation-fill-mode:both;animation-fill-mode:both;}
.boxwp-grid-snippet-mask-inside{position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;padding:8px;}
.boxwp-grid-post-thumbnail:hover .boxwp-grid-snippet-mask{opacity:0;bottom:-200px;}
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: Please include a simple demo that isolates the issue, with a giant wall of poorly formatted CSS and no HTML you're not likely to receive help.

Comment: Thank you. I cant include demo i dont know, i am trying to figure it out how the grid works

Comment: You also don't actually state what **is the problem**. - "Not right" doesn't actually mean anything

Comment: What I *suspect* is the issue is `justify-content:space-between;`

Comment: @Paulie_D My mistake ... https://imgur.com/yCiXY1Z this is the right behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alignment of cards inside flex box is currently set to align the cards with space between instead of left. Update the first property as below:

From:

`.boxwp-grid-posts { justify-content:space-between; }`

To:

`.boxwp-grid-posts { justify-content:left; }`

Comment: yep it worked but wordpress mentions that the justify-content: options are the following ... space-between , flex-start , flex-end, center , space-around ... but using left worked! do you know if this is going to create any strange behaviour in the interface?

Comment: justify-content:left; is valid but if wordpress is insisting on using one from above, justify-content: flex-start; should give you the same result.

Comment: yep i changed it to flex-start , same result thanks!